# program generate an undirected graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, graph

I'm a beginner in python, I'm having trouble solving an exercise on graph, the exercise is as follows:

A graph G = (V, A) stores the information of a set of vertices and a set of edges. The degree of a vertex is the number of edges incident on it. The degree of a graph is the maximum value of the degree of its vertices. The "D(degree)" is the inverse idea, the minimum value of the degree of the vertices. Write a program that takes a series of instructions and processes them to generate an undirected graph.

**IV A** inserts the vertex with **id==A** into the graph;

**IA A B** inserts an edge from the vertex of **id==A** to the vertex of **id==B**, if the vertices exist;

**RV A** removes the vertex of **id==A**, if it exists, and all edges related to it; and

**RA A B** removes the edge from the vertex of **id==A** to the vertex of **id==B**, if it exists;

**Input:**

The input consists of a line containing the number 0 ≤ n ≤ 100 indicating the number of operations on the graph, followed by n lines, each containing an instruction as shown. Each **id** is a string with a maximum of 10 characters.

**Exit:**

Present, in one line, the "D(degree)" of the graph.

**Note:**

Insert operations overwrite existing information. In the first example, the two vertices have the least number of edges. In the second case, vertex **A** has the fewest edges. In the last example, vertices **A** and **B** have only one edge while **C** has two.

[image]

this is the beginning of my code, as I couldn't develop:

```
n = int(input())

G = {}

for i in range(n):
  l = input().split()

  if l[0] == 'IV':
    if l[1] not in G:
      G[l[1]] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy actually. You have mentioned that `n <= 100`. So there might be atmost 200 different ids that can be introduced. Now we will maintain an array of 200x200

So you will do the following things:

1. Given those ids map them to integers always. Keep a dictionary and associate a number with it. So if you find they mention `IV A` then populate the dictionary with `{'A': 0}` and then if `IV B` populate it with `{A: 0, B: 1}` etc.
2. When you get an edge removal or addition case, check first if both vertices exists in the above mentioned dictionary.
3. In case they don't ignore it.
4. In case they do, then if it is addition of edge, the 2d array (which was initialized with 0) increase the corresponding entry.

`IA A B` --> Then you will add 1 to position `[0][1]` and `[1][0]` of 2d array.
`RA A B` --> Then you will subtract 1 from position `[0][1]` and `[1][0]` of 2d array.

In the end you will just count how many non-zero entries each row has (you will only considered the rows corresponding to IDs which appeared in the dictionary). And return the minimum one of them.